# Get full parms form url where script delete parms

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I use this simple code to get parms of url on updated tab

```
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function(tabId, changeInfo, tab,tabs) {

         chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
            var urladress=tabs[0].url;
            // do something with parms ;>

            console.log("Update: "+urladress);

        });
});
```

Its work fine when urls like http://www.foo.fo?a=A&b=b&c=C and site dont remove parms after load

but when site have sample code like this below to hide get parms after load cannot read parms:

```
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
```

console.log shows only www.foo.fo without parms :/

how to get the full url befor scirpt on site delete parms?

Comment: Is that possible to use content script to get the full url before loading the script of the site?

Comment: plugins like web developer can do very much so i think yes? :) the question is how?

Comment: This may give you some hints: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts